# Unable to verify Identityserver3 issued tokens

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

We have upgraded Identityserver3 to Identityserver4 and we are using IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation in API endpoints to verify jwt tokens.

After the upgrade we are unable to verify tokens issued by IdentityServer3.

We are able to use IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation by using the option LegacyAudienceValidation = true; to support tokens from Identityserver3 and Identityserver4.

IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation is based on .NET Core which we are not using. It is not an option to upgrade all our API endpoints to .NET Core and we need to be able to support Identityserver3 issued tokens.

How can we enable our existing API endpoint to support tokens issued by identityserver3 and identityserver4. Most of our API endpoints are based on Microsoft OWIN and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

Comment: Wait wait, something is not clear here. What version is your server - 3 or 4?

Comment: We currently use Identityserver4 but previously we used Identityserver3. This is the reason that we need to support both identityserver3  and identityserver4 issued tokens.

Comment: Why do you need to continue supporting identity server 3 tokens? They will be invalidated in 5mins?

Comment: The access tokens we have issued have a lifetime of 180 days therefore forcing us to keep supporting them otherwise all users needs to login again.

Comment: If your access_tokens are valid for 180 days, then you have a very serious problem. According to the specs and experts opinion the access token should be as short as possible. And this has its explanation - once issued, it cannot be invalidated, and 180 days is a very long period, to count on.

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 that you for your input, we are well aware of this issue. In our scenario it is actually a blessing as I believe we would not be able to migrate refresh tokens from identityserver3 - > identityserver4. We are currently look into solution which involves updating the discovery endpoint which looks promising. This solution has not yet been verified yet.